# Unable to copy local directory into Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm very new to a Docker. I want to copy a local directory to a Docker container but I get error

> file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat
> ~/.ssh: file does not exist

Here is the line of COPY code,

```
COPY ~/.ssh /root/.ssh
```

I can make sure that I have **~/.ssh** that it says dose not exist

[image]

I need to do this my Application throw error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (No such file or
> directory)

Then I've just realised that I need to copy it into a container.

In my app, I need to use **id_rsa** and **known_hosts** to connect to a SFTP server.

Please help. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: @Paolo No sir....

Comment: You generally don't want to `COPY` things like an ssh private key into a Docker image: anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially get the private key back out and use it.  The volume mount you suggest in an answer is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you can only use files from the directory where your `Dockerfile` is.

You cannot `ADD` or `COPY` files outside of the path local to the `Dockerfile`.

The solution is either mount `volume` with `docker run` or `docker-compose` (what you did already), or copy the directory `~/.ssh/` into your `Dockerfile` directory and then run `docker build` again.

Let's say we're in `/home/saeed/docker/` where your `Dockerfile` is located, and it has the following contents:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY .ssh /root/.ssh
```

Before running `docker build`, copy the required directory into the build directory:

```
cp -r ~/.ssh .
```

Then you can build and run your image as normal.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852628/docker-copy-failed-file-not-found-in-build-context-dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

I have not found the reason yet but I found the workaround by mounting the volume in docker-compose instead.

```yaml
- ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
```

But if someone could find the solution to my **COPY** problem I'm willing to learn it!