# Docker: COPY failed: file not found in build context (Dockerfile)

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'd like to instruct Docker to `COPY` my certificates from the local `/etc/` folder on my Ubuntu machine.

I get the error:

> COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by
> .dockerignore: stat etc/.auth_keys/fullchain.pem: file does not exist

I have not excluded in `.dockerignore`

How can I do it?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ./etc/.auth_keys/fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY ./etc/.auth_keys/privkey.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

I have also tried without the `dot` --> same error

```
COPY /etc/.auth_keys/fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY /etc/.auth_keys/privkey.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/
```

By placing the folder `.auth_keys` next to the Dockerfile --> works, but not desireable

```
COPY /.auth_keys/fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY /.auth_keys/privkey.pem /etc/nginx/ssl/
```

Comment: You can only `COPY` files that are located within your local source tree; you'll need to `cp` the files outside Docker space.  [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) discusses this further, though it's impractical to pass the entire host filesystem as the build context.

Comment: For the particular case of private keys, you shouldn't `COPY` them into an image, though, since they can be very easily copied back out.  The `docker run -v` option or Compose `volumes:` can [inject arbitrary host content into a container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) and isn't subject to `COPY`'s path restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, very useful and concise answer, May I please ask what a common solution is, to safety handle those keys in a production environment (by a separate script?)

Comment: In my case, I was just overworked and didn't realize that what I'm trying to copy doesn't exist on the host. 
`COPY filexyz /src/filexyz`
Now, my current working directory on host didn't have any filexyz file so it failed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The docker context is the directory the Dockerfile is located in. If you want to build an image that is one of the restrictions you have to face.

In [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) you can see how contexts can be switched, but to keep it simple just consider the same directory to be the context. Note; this also doesn't work with symbolic links.

So your observation was correct and you need to place the files you need to copy in the same directory.

Alternatively, if you don't need to copy them but still have them available at runtime you could opt for a mount. I can imagine this not working in your case because you likely need the files at startup of the container.

Comment: Bind-mounted files will be available at container startup (when the `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` runs) but not before (during `RUN` steps).  For keys used to sign and encrypt TLS network traffic this is probably fine.

Answer (score 16):

@JustLudo's answer is correct, in this case. However, for those who have the correct files in the build directory and **still** seeing this issue; remove any trailing comments.

Coming from a C and javascript background, one may be forgiven for assuming that trailing comments are ignored (e.g. `COPY my_file /etc/important/ # very important!`), but they are not! The error message won't point this out, as of my version of docker (20.10.11).

For example, the above erroneous line will give an error:

`COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat etc/important/: file does not exist`

... i.e. no mention that it is the trailing `# important!` that is tripping things up.

Answer (score 15):

It's also important to note that, as [mentioned into the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/):

> If you use STDIN or specify a URL pointing to a plain text file, the system places the contents into a file called Dockerfile, and any -f, --file option is ignored. In this scenario, **there is no context**.

That is, if you're running `build` like this:

```
docker build -t dh/myimage - < Dockerfile_test
```

Any `COPY` or `ADD`, having no context, will throw the error mentioned or another similar:

```
failed to compute cache key: "xyz" not found: not found
```

If you face this error and you're piping your `Dockerfile`, then I advise to use `-f` to target a custom `Dockerfile`.

```
docker build -t dh/myimage -f Dockerfile_test .
```

(`.` set the context to the current directory)

---

Here is a test you can do yourself :

1. In an empty directory, create a `Dockerfile_test` file, with this content

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine
COPY test_file /my_test_file
```

2. Then create a dummy file:

```
touch test_file
```

3. Run `build` piping the test `Dockerfile`, see how it fails *because it has no context*:

```
docker build -t dh/myimage - < Dockerfile_test
[..]
failed to compute cache key: "/test_file" not found: not found
[..]
```

4. Now run `build` with `-f`, see how the same `Dockerfile` works *because it has context*:

```
docker build -t dh/myimage -f Dockerfile_test .
[..]
 => [2/2] COPY test_file /my_test_file
 => exporting to image
[..]
```

Comment: I had this problem because I was building using STDIN thank you for the insight

Answer (score 2):

Let me share my solution

Here is the outline of my project

```
├-app
 ├── Dockerfile
 ├── pom.xml
 ├── src
```

Now my docker command was to be fired from a directory outside of app and not inside app folder.
So this is what worked for me

```
docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f app/Dockerfile app
```

Note the context which is generally specified as "." was now replaced with the "app" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your docker-compos.yml, it might be changing the context directory.

I had a similar problem, with the only clarification: I was running Dockerfile with docker-compos.yml

This is what my Dockerfile looked like when I got the error:

```
FROM alpine:3.17.0
ARG DB_NAME \
    DB_USER \
    DB_PASS
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --no-cache \
    php \
    ...
EXPOSE 9000
COPY ./conf/www.conf /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d   #<--- an error was here
COPY ./tools /var/www/                         #<--- and here
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/var/www/start.sh"]
```

This is part of my docker-compose.yml where I described my service.

```
wordpress:
container_name: wordpress
build:
  context: .          #<--- the problem was here
  dockerfile: requirements/wordpress/Dockerfile
  args:
    DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
    DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
    DB_PASS: ${DB_PASS}
ports:
  - "9000:9000"
depends_on:
  - mariadb
restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  - inception
volumes:
  - wp:/var/www/
```

My docker-compos.yml was changing the context directory. Then I wrote a new path in the Dockerfile and it all worked.

```
COPY ./requirements/wordpress/conf/www.conf /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d
COPY ./requirements/wordpress/tools /var/www/
```

[*project structure*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeFSb.png)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW this same error shows up when running `gcloud builds submit` if the files are included in `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a simlink with ln -s to the /etc/certs/ folder in the docker build directory?

Alternatively you could have one image that has the certificates and in your image you just COPY FROM the docker image having the certs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was same error:

`ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src/: file does not exist`

I had: `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_db_root_pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
      MYSQL_USER: my_db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_db_pass
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

and
`Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

When I created a src folder and then added an index.php file to the src folder for example

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Docker</title>
  </head>
  <body><p>Docker</p></body>
</html>
```

Everything worked

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker} .
```

Publish folder in Docker folder was not available

Answer (score -1):

I merely had quoted the source file while building a windows container, e.g.,
`COPY "file with space.txt" c:/some_dir/new_name.txt`
Docker doesn't like the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

1. I had the same error. I resolved it by adding this to my Docker `build` command:

```
docker build --no-cache -f ./example-folder/example-folder/Dockerfile
```

- This repoints Docker to the home directory. Even if your `Dockerfile` seems to run (i.e. the system seems to locate it and starts running it), I found I needed to have the home directory pre-defined above, for any copying to happen.

2. Inside my `Dockerfile`, I had the file copying like this:

```
COPY ./example-folder/example-folder /home/example-folder/example-folder
```