# Dockerfile not building in Azure

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile that is working on my local machine but is not working on my azure pipelines build.

I've referenced this link here: [Docker: COPY failed: file not found in build context (Dockerfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852628/docker-copy-failed-file-not-found-in-build-context-dockerfile) but was unable to get the docker context for my solution to work properly.

```
Project File Structure:
AzureProject.sln
|AzureProject
|Classes
||DockerFile
||AzureProject.csproj
.dockerignore
.gitignore
```

My Docker file is the default file built on creation when you select "include docker" with your .NET 6 project. Again located in: AzureProject/Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AzureProject/AzureProject.csproj", "AzureProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AzureProject/AzureProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AzureProject"
RUN dotnet build "AzureProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AzureProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AzureProject.dll"]
```

Lastly, my azure-pipelines.yml file looks like

```
 steps:
 - task: Docker@2
  displayName: buildAndPush
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: AzureCR
    repository: AzureCR-NET6
    Dockerfile: AzureProject/Dockerfile
```

Edit 1: [Folder Structure in VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rdl9.png)

Comment: Can you please format your directory structure with proper indentation instead of pipes? I can't make any sense of what structure you're trying to indicate.

Comment: I've added an image of the folder structure in VSCode

Comment: How the project is laid out in visual studio isn't important here. The **actual, on-disk** directory structure is what's important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to discover the solution after looking at the structure on the disk as opposed to in VS thanks to Daniel's suggestion. Found out it was a folder hierarchy issue and that I was being dense by not just looking at it in File Explorer, definitely user error.

To sum up the issue, Dockerfile was building in local but when pushed to a repository and then put through Azure Pipelines the build was failing saying it was unable to find the files for the COPY [AzureProject/AzureProject.csproj, AzureProject/] this was due to the DockerFile being one directory too low, and needed to be moved up a folder so that it had the correct context.

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSAdS.png)