# Error building Docker image: “COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore”

Tags: docker

I’m trying to build a Docker image using a Dockerfile, but I’m getting an error at the COPY step. Here is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu as build

RUN apt update && apt install -y python3 && apt clean

COPY teste.py /opt/teste.py

CMD python3 /opt/teste.py
```

When I run the command

```
docker build -t ubuntu-python .
```

, I get the following error:

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat opt/teste.py: file does not exist
```

However, the teste.py file exists in the same directory as the Dockerfile.

Comment: What does your `docker build` command look like and from which directory do you run it from? The same as where the `teste.py` file exists? You have to make sure you have the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/) setup properly (i. e. you basically have to tell Docker which files to consider and which not). Also just to be sure check your `.dockerignore` file (if you have one in the same directory) whether it excludes the `teste.py` file e.g. by specifying the directory it's in or some wildcard like `*.py` (it's unlikely though that that is the case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: COPY failed: file not found in build context (Dockerfile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852628/docker-copy-failed-file-not-found-in-build-context-dockerfile)

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -al` in the same directory where you ran the `docker build` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your build command

```
docker build -t ubuntu-python .
```

specifies that the current working directory (`.`) is the Docker build context. So that's where the `COPY` command is looking for the `teste.py` file.

As mentioned in comments you should check that

- the file is located in that directory and
- the file is not matched by any entry in `.dockerignore`.